# Deploying shinyapps on a desktop

Tags: r, shiny, desktop

I have a shiny app that runs perfectly on my computer and shinyapps.io.  This app is being built for a client where i need to share it to run on their desktops.  I have used the guidance given on this [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/deploying-desktop-apps-with-r/).

The first line of my shiny server reads a RDS file and loads the data.  I have copied the RDS within the shiny folder as given in the example shared above.  My current folder looks like this:

```
C:/dist/
GoogleChromePortable
R-Portable
shiny - within shiny folder i have ui.R, server.R, lhg.RDS
run.vbs
runShinyApp.R
```

run.vbs

```
Randomize
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "R-Portable\App\R-Portable\bin\i386\R.exe CMD BATCH --vanilla --slave runShinyApp.R" & " " & RND & " ", 0, False
```

runShinyApp.R

```
.libPaths("./R-Portable/App/R-Portable/library")
browser.path <- file.path(getwd(),"GoogleChromePortable/GoogleChromePortable.exe")
options(browser = browser.path)
shiny::runApp("./Shiny/",port=8888,launch.browser=TRUE)
```

My server begins like this:

```
lhg <- readRDS(file.path(getwd(),"LHG.RDS"))
```

When I run the vbs file, it opens a browser, but throws a error message:

```
Error:object "lhg" not found
```

And everytime I run, the error creates a new file with some random numbers that contains the logs of the same error.

Can someone help please?

Comment: Your file paths seem inconsistent... your `.libPaths` addition is in relation to the working directory, wherever that is by default for R-Portable, your `chrome.portable` and `runApp()` paths are hard-coded from `C:/` (seems like making a strong assumption about where things are), and you don't show the where you're looking for the `lhg` file. I don't have a solution, but I think you need to work out where your working directory is and go from there.

Comment: A good diagnosis tool might be to make a simple shiny app that just prints its working directory and stick it in the same framework.

Comment: @Gregor I have made changes to my code on specifying the working directory...also I have included the line from server.R that reads the rds file. With the changes in server.R, the app initiates without a problem in my original code, but throws the same error, in the portable version.  And these are two different machines.

Comment: You can `print` the `getwd()` or `save` to a text file to check the  working  directory.

Comment: @Bangyou Many thanks....Apparently, I figured i have to specify the path both in UI as well as in Server, which I did.  The application opened flawlessly couple of times, post which it stalled.  The error log read "connection reset by peer".  I reinstalled shiny, but the problem continues.  Kind of quite tricky, especially, I know only how to work in R and not in Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try out the RInno package (I just published it to CRAN last month). It helps automate these types of desktop deployments, and you should be able to get setup with:

```
install.packages("RInno")
require(RInno)
RInno::install_inno()
```

The directory containing ui.R & server.R is `app_dir`:

```
create_app(app_name = "Your app's name", app_dir = "path/to/app_dir")
compile_iss()
```

The resulting installer should install your app "as is," so you don't need to manage those tricky working directory issues. If it works in your dev environment, it should work after it is installed. If you'd like more resources on how to customize your installation, check out [FI Labs - RInno](http://www.ficonsulting.com/filabs/RInno)